# Get an available IP address from a dhcp server

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have a c# desktop app.

I have an ip camera and I want to assign a static ipaddress to it.  I need to be able to get a 'free/available' ip address from  my dhcp server, reserve it and assign it to my ip camera. I can assign the ip address to my camera easily enough. But how do I get an available ip address and reserve it before it is allocated to another device 'plugged' into my network?

I have seen api calls to get client ipaddresses but do not see if I can use it for what I want.

I could ping each ip address on the subnet in order to find if an address is available but that seems inefficient as i would be waiting for a time out from pinging that address.  Besides, it would not 'reserve' it.

I hope I making this clear?

NB.
I want to assign a static ip address to my ip camera. I have the sdk to do that. It is just that I need to assign a free ip address that is on the same subnet

Comment: I'm not clear on how you are using a DHCP server to assign a static IP. Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: Yes, quite right.  I can assign a static IP address to the IP camera.  It needs to be on the same subnet. So, to explain further the ip camera comes pre-configured on 192.168.100.100 (factory setting). Now I can call a url with that IP address and say 'yes use a static ip address but I am on this subnet'. I will amend my question as you are correct :) thank you!

Comment: What you want to do needs to be set in your DHCP Server (probably your router). Stackoverflow is not the most suited network. Try it over at http://serverfault.com AFAIK, you cannot accomplish this from the client, using standard code.

Comment: From what I can tell, simply starting with Wikipedia might be sufficient. It contains information on the conversation you need to have with the DHCP server and even some (all?) of the packet format information. It should at least get you going: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol  You might have to spoof the MAC address of the camera somehow, which might imply disconnecting it during the DHCP stuff... If nothing else, you'll have a decent understanding of DHCP.

Comment: Steve, thank you.  I will look at that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IP Camera would need to support either the DHCP Protocol, or be able to be assigned a Static IP Address.  If it supports the DHCP Camera then it will handle it on your own, but if it must be assigned a static IP address, then you would need to reserve that IP addres son the router, and then enter it into the camera as it's static IP address.

Routers use the MAC Address to assign out IP's under the DHCP. Unless you have a system that can masquerade as the IP Camera using it's MAC Address, to retrieve an IP address from the DHCP router, your stuck with one of the two ways above to assign an IP.

Comment: To the 1st part of your answer. Yes, you are correct. My original question was flawed. I have amended.  The 2nd part of your answer is informative and I need to go away and think about it. I will report back when I do :)

Comment: To masquerade the MAC address, your going to need access to RAW Sockets.

Also would help to know what platform your doing this on? and what Language?

Comment: HI, I am using C# and Windows 7 (but will need to support Windows 8)

Comment: Not a C# expert, but did look this up.  You can create a RAW Socket under C# by creating your Socket with ProtocolType.Raw. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx can provide you with additional help on the sockets class.

What kind of camera is this?  If it's an IP Camera and doesn't support DHCP, I'm kinda shocked.

Answer (score 1):

Some routers will let you statically assign an ip address to a device through the admin web UI. It that's the case with your router you can just let it connect to an ip address and tell the router to always assign your device that ip.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. But I need to handle this all through my code without manual intervention by a User.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I don't suppose your router has an SSH interface or similar you could hit with your program?  Or does this need to work with many types of routers?

Comment: hi, I do not know. I could certainly find out. But if it did I would not be able to guarantee whether a different installation network would have it as well :(

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the DHCP request needs to come with the MAC address that you want to assign it to. If the camera doesn't support DHCP, you can't ask for an address in its name.

The simplest thing to do for you might be to implement a poor man's NAT between the user's computer and the camera: you would forward traffic from certain ports of the user's computer to the camera, and forward responses from the camera to the person who asked for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I will look into this and see how I can apply it and I will report back. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If the machine and camera are on the same switch, you could use a different subnet for the NAT to avoid cross-talk between the two networks using only a single physical network.

Comment: Hi, yes I did do that originally.  I left it on the factory set ip address which was static 192.168.100.100.  This worked OK but when I installed at a friends who already was using a static ipaddress for his server (bought from O2) the internet was thrown out for some reason. I admit I am learning this stuff as i type :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson well if your friend was on 192.168.0.0 you could switch to 10.0.0.0 etc.  (Note: if your software and his router were both only using say 192.168.42.0 there shouldn't have been a problem, but if one had a netmask of 255.255.0.0 you'd be in trouble)

Comment: @ebyrob Hi, thanks for taking an interest. I just checked and his static ip server address is 192.168.1.1 and his subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Yes, but what is *your* subnet mask?  (255.255.0.0 or 255.255.255.0?)

Comment: OH, I see I am not sure {duh} and the ip cameras can be of different makes/models and thus different default settings